# In PowerShell Get-ChildItem -Exclude is not working with -Recurce parameter

Tags: powershell

[image]I want to search all directory recursively except the directory which starts with `_`(underscore).

Ex: `_archive`, `_DO_NOT_DELETE`, `_processing`, etc.

I used below code and it is not working. It seems exclude will not work with recurse . Any ideas?

```cs
$exclude = @("_*")
$source = "C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\" 
$allitems = Get-ChildItem $source -Directory -Exclude $exclude -Recurse
foreach($myItem in $allitems)
{
  echo $myItem.fullname
}
```

**Output:**

```
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder\New folder
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder (2)
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder (3)
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder (3)\New folder
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\_archive\New folder
```

So, as I told before I want to avoid the directory started with underscore, hence the last line should not come.

Even I used below code as well, still same output:

```cs
$exclude = @("_*")
$source = "C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\"
$allitems = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Directory |
            Where {$_.FullName -notlike $exclude}
foreach($myItem in $allitems)
{
    echo $myItem.fullname
}
```

Comment: @Paxz The `-exclude` switch accepts arrays. For example `-exclude "*.txt","*.log" is valid syntax.`

Comment: @vonPryz yeah, noticed myself.

Comment: I tried with -exclude "_*" as well....Actually both are same. @Paxz for your information in my case if i remove -recurse , the exclude part it is working.

Comment: Is the space intended? `\ _archive` or `\_archive`?

Comment: Well it kind of is working as intended, it didn't show you the folder `C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\ _archive` only its subfolder, you could build a loop around it, but there probaly is a better way...

Comment: @vonPryz  my bad!! space is not there, the directory name is "_archive" only .

Comment: the problem with exclude is that it only works on leafs on the path structure

Answer (score 4):

What happens here is that Get-ChildItem's `-exclude` parameter works based on item's name property. When wildcards are being used, the name must match the non-wildcarded parts. This doesn't happen when your directory name begins with a space. Let's see an example:

```
# Create two files, one starts with a space, the other doesn't
Set-Content -Path " data1.txt" -Value $null
Set-Content -Path "data2.txt" -Value $null

gci -name "data*"
 data2.txt

gci -name " data*"
 data1.txt
```

The result is a single match, tough a wildcard was used. The reason is that `data1.txt`'s first character is a space and that doesn't match parameter's first character, namely `d`.

The `-exclude` is notorious for being tricky. It is often easier to work around by piping results to `where-object`. Like so,

```
Get-ChildItem $source -Directory -recurse | ? {$_.fullname -NotMatch "\\\s*_"} | % { $_.fullname }
# "\\\s*_" is regex for \, any amount of whitespace, _ 
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder (2)
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder (3)
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder\New folder
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\New folder\New folder (3)\New folder

Get-ChildItem $source -Directory -recurse | ? {$_.fullname -Match "\\\s*_"} | % { $_.fullname }
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\ _archive
C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\ _archive\New folder
```

Note that the matching needs to evaluate `FullName` property. Just using `Name` would match only the leaf level.

Comment: My bad!! space is not there, the directory name is "_archive" only .

Answer (score 2):

Haven't found an answer to the first attempt. But if you want to go with `Where-Object` you have to change your Filter from `_*` to `*_*`.

This is because `.Fullname` displays the full path, so alot more characters before the actual `_` of the Path.

```
$exclude = @("*_*")
$source = "C:\code\Powershell\delete empty folders\New folder\"
$allitems = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Directory | Where {$_.FullName -notlike $exclude}
$allitems.Fullname
```

Should give you the expected output.

Comment: My bad!! space is not there, the directory name is "_archive" only .

Comment: That doesn't work for more than 1 exclude filter. Do this if you need more. ```Get-ChildItem $source -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.FullName | Select-String -SimpleMatch -NotMatch $xclds }```

Answer (score 2):

As @Paxz says in the comments, the command is working as intended, just not as you'd hoped.  It is definitely excluding the folders starting with `_` from the output, but this does not apply to the `-Recurse` switch, so it still looks inside those folders for other items, which it displays (if their name does not start with `_`).

You can use your own filter to get what you want:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory -recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.FullName -notlike "*\_*"} |
        Format-Table FullName
```

Note that this still finds all the folders with `_`, but just discards them (so, no performance improvement).  Also, using the simpler filter: `-notlike "*_*"` would exclude any folder with an underscore in the middle or end of its name (e.g. `Hello_World`), not just the beginning.

Comment: @Paxz, Hmmm .. not intentionally.  I did try to edit it and maybe something went wrong.  I've removed the duplicate.

Comment: My bad!! space is not there, the directory name is "_archive" only .